# Plastic or rubber stretched too much is (hardly/strongly) stretched?

Tags: meaning, word-usage, adverbs

If you want to describe a stretched plastic cable, would you say that it was *hardly stretched* or *strongly stretched*?

Comment: _Hardly_ is a confusing word: in modern English, it always means "only a little bit", and is never used as an adverbial form of _hard_. The adverb corresponding to _hard_ is in fact "hard", as in "He pulled it hard" or "I tried hard", or "They hit him hard".

Comment: A [question to go](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/5656/hard-vs-hardly) with what Colin has explained.

Answer (score 10):

Actually you say neither.

*Hardly* stretched means that it is barely stretched at all.  (Although I see where your confusion arises) and *strongly* stretched is not something a native speaker would say.

They would say [***overstretched***](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/overstretched) in the case it is stretched too much, and [***tightly stretched***](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/tightly) when the cable is quite taut but not overly so.

Answer (score 0):

I have never heard either of these words used with stretched.  In fact, the connotation of hardly in the phrase "hardly stretched" means "barely".  See the fourth definition from merriam-webster.com:

> 1 : with force : VIGOROUSLY
>
> 2 : in a severe manner : HARSHLY
>
> 3 : with difficulty : PAINFULLY
>
> 4 : a - used to emphasize a minimal amount < I *hardly* knew her > < almost new - *hardly* a scratch on it >
>
> b - used to soften a negative < you can't *hardly* tell who anyone is - G. B. Shaw >
>
> 5 : certainly not < that news is *hardly* surprising >

While definitions 1 and 2 do mean what you are intending, the phrase is more typically used to mean "barely".

I would use "tightly stretched" to mean something that is stretched as far as it can go.

Comment: Disagree with last assertion; *tightly stretched* does not imply “stretched as far as it can go”.  Yes, a thing that's tightly stretched *might* be stretched as far as it can be, but in general [more stress gives more strain](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stress%E2%80%93strain_curve).

Comment: I also disagree that (1) and (2) are good fits for the OP's purpose.  "Vigorously stretched" and "harshly stretched" are not commonly used phrases.

Comment: Sorry for the misunderstanding - I was not suggesting "vigorously" or "harshly"; I meant that the OP meant "hardly" for the definitions of "with force" or "in a severe manner" but I was arguing that the use rather implies the 4th definition.

Comment: @Kristina Lopez: Not *that* common, maybe, but ["vigorously stretched"](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=%22vigorously+stretched%22&btnG=Search+Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1) and ["stretched vigorously"](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=%22stretched+vigorously%22&btnG=Search+Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1) both occur hundreds of times in Google Books. Not to mention ["stretch vigorously"](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=%22stretch+vigorously%22&btnG=Search+Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1) and other variants.

Comment: @FumbleFingers, Google Books may have hundreds of hits but stretching vigorously sounds a bit contradictory because stretching is progressive and vigorously is, well, vigorous! (Possibly my worst argument yet! Lol!)

Comment: @Kristina Lopez: "worst argument yet" <nods head vigorously>. Have you never kneaded bread dough? That's primarily for the purpose of "stretching" it - but it should be done reasonably vigorously (if only to help you work up an appetite for the finished product :)

Comment: @FumbleFingers, touche! Yes! Kneading bread dough IS stretching vigorously! Brilliant example! :-)